# How can I create a method to detect when a notification is clicked using xamarin coss-platform portable?

Tags: xamarin, notifications, cross-platform, portability

I´m a bit new to Xamarin Forms development, but not to Android (Java) development. Here´s the scenario:

I´ve developed an app for android, which schedules notifications (NotificationManager) and adds an intent to each notification in order to redirect the user to a specific url inside a webview. The url came from the notification intent.

So, I´m doing exactly the same thing in xamarin, in order to build the iOS version. Since I´m also an ASP.NET, I chose this method.

I´ve done all the basic stuff, so far:

created the webview with the right address;
created the routine which sets the cross-platform notifications using CrossLocalNotifications (Xam.Plugins.Notifier)
This is the problem:
I need to create a method in which the app redirects (webview) the user, once he clicks the notifications, in the portable solution level. I think I can manage to develop the logic to use the webview I currently have. I just can´t seem to find anywhere on the web a tip for creating a method to "listen" to the user click and catch information (or just the ID) of the notification created, so I can build the routine.

Anyone can help or have a better solution?

Comment: did you get any solution?